# How do I simplify a program?

Tags: python, date, simplify

I am trying to create a program in python 3 that can output calendar dates correctly. There are many inputs including the month, day, and year. Given these inputs, the the output should be month/day/year (e.g. jan/26/1876). One thing I have to be aware of however is the maximum days per month (e.g 31 days versus 30 for some months). I successfully created a program  that allows certain months to exceed 30 days (January, March, May, etc.). However, my code is VERY inefficient. I used a list called "months" to store in each month and determined their max. days each with brackets. I would use an if statement to show whether months[month - 1] == (months[0] (January) or months[2] (March)). However, the program reads it as equal to January or does March exist (which it does in every case). This is the most efficient way (I found) to produce my code, and it does not work. Here is my code:

```
# calendar.py

month = int(input("Put in the month: "))
day = int(input("Put in the day: "))
year = int(input("Put in the year: "))
months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"]

# Source of inefficiency (along others)
if months[month - 1] == months[0] or months[month - 1] == months[2] or months[month - 1] == months[4] or months[month - 1] == months[6] or months[month - 1] == months[7] or months[month - 1] == months[9] or months[month - 1] == months[11]:

    if day > 31:

        print("Invalid date")

    else:

        months[month - 1] = str(months[month - 1])
        day = str(day)
        year = str(year)

        print(months[month - 1] + "/" + day + "/" + year)

else:

    if day > 30:

        print("Invalid date")

    else:

        months[month - 1] = str(months[month - 1])
        day = str(day)
        year = str(year)

        print(months[month - 1] + "/" + day + "/" + year)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to have a list of month lengths, for example:

```
days_in_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

if day > days_in_month[month-1]:
    print('Invalid date', file=sys.stderr)
    # ... exit, e.g. sys.exit(1)
```

(Obviously, you still need special logic to handle leap years.)

Answer (score 0):

You can let the standard [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library do the check.

Just call `datetime.date(year, month, day)` If there is no such day, a `ValueError` will be raised. Leap year handling included.

```
>>> import datetime as dt
>>> dt.date(2019,2,29)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: day is out of range for month
>>> dt.date(2020,2,29)
datetime.date(2020, 2, 29)
```